# symfony2 detect locale based on domain name

Tags: locale, symfony-2.1

i want to setup a new website with 2 locales and the locale should detected by the domain name that's used. Any idea how to do this?

```
for example locales: nl and fr
when www.somenldomainname.be is used then the nl locale should be detected
when www.somefrdomainname.be is used then the fr locale should be detected
```

it would also be great if i generate an url in nl or fr the right domain name is selected.

kind regards,

Daan

Answer (score 3):

You can create an event listener to detect your domain name:

```
class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /**
     * Set default locale
     *
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }
        // get domain name
        $host = $request->getHttpHost();
        // or $host = $request->getHost();
        $locale = 'en';
        if ($host == 'domain1') {
            $locale = 'fr';
        } 
        $request->setLocale($locale);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    static public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
```

}

And in your services.yml:

```
services:

    my_locale_listener:
        class: MyBundle\LocaleListener
        tags:
            -  { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

You can put in listener constructor default locle from parameters.yml file and if locale is not detected by domain set default locale.

Comment: there isn't a more build in way to do this? Because for generating the urls i'll need to overwrite the url generator then i presume ...

Answer (score 3):

There is a bundle for that: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle.

This is how you set it up in `config.yml`:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: nl
    locales: [nl, fr]
    strategy: custom
    hosts:
        nl: www.somenldomainname.be
        fr: www.somefrdomainname.be
redirect_to_host: true
```

See [documentation on usage scenarios](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/configuration) for more details.

Comment: Will this just a redirect to host by locale? I guess it should work in opposite manner - set locale  by host

Comment: Yes, it will detect locale by host, not vice versa. I run one project on 2 domains that uses this bundle.

Answer (score 1):

The bundle JMSI18nRoutingBundle only supports symfony <=2.1.x.
The good way seems to use the solution of Daniel Korsak. Here is a more complete exemple with parameters.

```
namespace Path\ToYourBundle\Listeners;

use \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $domainLocales;
    protected $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($container,$defaultLocale)
    {
        $this->domainLocales = $container->getParameter('domain_locales');
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }
    /**
     * Set default locale
     *
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }
        // get domain name
        $host = $request->getHttpHost();
        // or $host = $request->getHost();

        $locale = $this->defaultLocale;


        if (array_key_exists($host, $this->domainLocales))
        {
            $locale = $this->domainLocales[$host];
        }
        $request->setLocale($locale);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    static public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

And in your services.yml:

```
services:

    my_locale_listener:
        class: Path\ToYourBundle\Listeners\LocaleListener
        tags:
            -  { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
        arguments: [@service_container,%locale%]
parameters:
    domain_locales:
        domain1: en
        domain2: fr
```